# adding a comma in the text file

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a text file in the following format

```
group1: 2010EL-1749 2010EL-1749_00001 3554-08 3554-08_01855 2010EL-1749_00002
group2: 2010EL-1749 2010EL-1749_00002 3554-08 3554-08_01856 2010EL-1749_00001
group7: 3554-08 2010EL-1749_00001 3554-08_01855
```

And would like to add a comma in between the ids as shown below

```
group1: 2010EL-1749,2010EL-1749_00001,3554-08,3554-08_01855,2010EL-1749_00002
group2: 2010EL-1749,2010EL-1749_00002,3554-08,3554-08_01856,2010EL-1749_00001
group7: 3554-08,2010EL-1749_00001,3554-08_01855
```

Comment: Is it possible for any of the IDs to contain spaces?

Comment: No they do not have spaces.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/ /,/g; s/,/ /' textfile
group1: 2010EL-1749,2010EL-1749_00001,3554-08,3554-08_01855,2010EL-1749_00002
group2: 2010EL-1749,2010EL-1749_00002,3554-08,3554-08_01856,2010EL-1749_00001
group7: 3554-08,2010EL-1749_00001,3554-08_01855
```

This works by changing all spaces to commas: `s/ /,/g`.  It then changes the first comma back to a space: `s/,/ /`.

`s/,/ /` is an example of a *substitute* command.  The form is `s/old/new/` where `old` is a *regular expression* and the first match for `old` is replaced with `new`.  If we add a `g` to the end of the command, like `s/ /,/g`, then not just the first is replaced: all non-overlapping matches are replaced.

This approach assumes that no ID contains a space and no group name contains a comma.

To change the file in place:

```
sed -i.bak 's/ /,/g; s/,/ /' textfile
```

#### Alternatives

As suggested by sp asic in the comments, if we can assume that all IDs end with a number, then:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\) /\1,/g' textfile
```

Or, if instead we can assume that only groups, not IDs, end with a colon (Hat tip: James Brown):

```
sed 's/\([^:]\) /\1,/g' testfile
```

Comment: assuming all IDs end with a number, `sed 's/\([0-9]\) /\1,/g' textfile`

Comment: @spasic That is also an interesting approach:  I just added it to the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: To make it a bit (well a byte) shorter: `sed 's/\([^:]\) /\1,/g' testfile`

Comment: @JamesBrown Very good.  I added that to the answer also.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In AWK, replace all spaces with commas and then the first comma back to space:

`awk 'gsub(/ /,",") && sub(/,/," ")' testfile`

or using `gensub`:

`awk '$0=gensub(/([^:]) /,"\\1,","g")' testfile`